# Последовательные запросы axios в цикле

Tags: javascript, axios

Как выполнить последовательные axios запросы в цикле for?

```
for (let i=0; i < this.files.items.length; i++) {
                let params = new FormData();
                params.set('file', this.files.items[i].blob );
                const options = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'ProjectId' : this.$route.params.hash
                    },
                };
                this.$http
                    .post(`${this.$serverApiLink}docs/changes/create`, params, options)
                    .then(
                        response => {

                        }
                    )
                    .catch(
                        error => {

                        }
                    );
            }
```

Нужно, что бы новый запрос в цикле выполнялся после окончания предыдущего, а не сразу все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sendFile(index) {
  if (index >= this.files.items.length)
    return;

  let params = new FormData();
  params.set('file', this.files.items[index].blob );
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'ProjectId' : this.$route.params.hash
    },
  };
  this.$http
    .post(`${this.$serverApiLink}docs/changes/create`, params, options)
    .then(
      response => {
        sendFile.call(this, index + 1);
      }
    )
    .catch(
      error => {

      }
    );
}
sendFile.call(this, 0);
```